# Phantomjs code help in taking search value from another external script present in local drive

Tags: phantomjs

my problem is: unable combine and to execute these two scripts as one..i have tried a lot of parse errors..please help me to execute it in one script sucessfully.

a.) frist (childprocess.js) ---- it output search text which is to be fed in search box of script google.js

```
  var process = require("child_process")
  var execFile = process.execFile

 execFile("python", ["C:\\PhantomJS\\phantomjs\\pyt.py"], null, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  var a = JSON.stringify(stdout);
  var t = {};
  t.substr = a.substr(1,20);
  var ocr = t.substr;
  console.log(ocr);
  })
  setTimeout(function (ocrad) {
  phantom.exit(1)
  }, 2000)
```

---

b.) second script (google.js) --- it will take search value and take screenshot of it..

```
   var page = require("webpage").create();
   var homePage = "http://www.google.com/";

        page.open(homePage);
        page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
        var url = page.url;

       console.log("Status:  " + status);
       console.log("Loaded:  " + url);

       if (url === homePage) {
       page.includeJs("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js", function() {
  console.log("Loaded jQuery!");
  page.evaluate(function() {
    var searchBox = $("#.lst");
    var stringbox =$("#text_bost");
    var searchForm = $("form1");
    //value to be got from first script
    searchBox.val("first script output value"); 
    stringBox.val("oracleapps");
    searchForm.submit();
     });
    });
    } else {
    page.render("results.png");
   phantom.exit();
 }
 };
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. Can you edit your question to include the code that unsuccessfully combined. Please add the output, errors and a description how you want it to behave.

Comment: Thanks Artom B I have done the home work...the above given two scripts runs exactly fine.. and I want to merge it and have one program...so as to get the desired page render to me!!